# Wrapping all AJAX calls jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I populate many parts of my website using

```
$("#theDivToPopulate").load("/some/api/call.php", callBackToBindClickEventsToNewDiv);
```

Where /some/api/call.php returns a built list, div, or some other HTML structure to place directly into my target div.  The internet has been running slow lately and I've noticed that the time between a button click (which kicks off these API calls) and the div populating is several seconds.  Is there an easy way to globally wrap all the load calls so that a div containing "Loading..." is displayed before the call is even made and hidden once the API call is complete.

I can not simply put the code to hide the div into the callBackToBindClickEventsToNewDiv as some load events have different call backs.  I would have to copy the code into each function which is ugly and defeats the purpose.  I want the flow of any .load to go as follows:

```
 1) dispplayLoadingDiv()
 2) Execute API call
 3) Hide loading div
 4) do callback function.
```

The loading div must be hidden first as the callback contains some animations to bring the newly loaded div in nicely.

EDIT:
Expanding on jacktheripper's answer:

```
var ajaxFlag;
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    ajaxFlag = true;
    setTimeout(function (e) {
        if(ajaxFlag) {
            hideAllDivs();
            enableDivs(['loading']);
        }
    }, 500);

}).ajaxStop(function(){
    ajaxFlag = false;
    var load = $("#loading");
    load.css('visibility','hidden');
    load.css('display','none');
    load.data('isOn',false);
});
```

This way loading is only displayed if the page takes more than 500 MS to load.  I found the loading flying in and out real fast made things kind of choppy for fast page loads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){ 
    $('#loader').show(); 
}).ajaxStop(function(){ 
    $('#loader').hide();
});
```

Where you have an element called `#loader` that contains what you want to show when an AJAX request is being performed. It could be a span with text, an image (eg a gif), or anything similar. The element should be initially set to `display: none`

You do not even need to call the function anywhere else.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.  When the API calls are fast the div comes and goes so quickly it is not noticeable.  When they are slow loading is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#someButtonId").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#theDivToPopulate").html("Loading...");
   $.get("/some/api/call.php",function(data){
       $("#theDivToPopulate").fadeOut(100,function(){
           $("#theDivToPopulate").html(data).fadeIn(100,function(){
               //Do your last call back after showing the content
           });
      });
   });    
});
```